# Debian package translation

Tags: packaging, debian

I’m a beginner to Debian packaging and programming in general. I have built a Debian package for my python script and want to make it available for translating into other languages. What should I add to the package? Or do I have to rebuild it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For translation of the package description there is nothing special that you need to do, it will be handled automatically by the [Debian Description Translation Project (DDTP)](https://www.debian.org/international/l10n/ddtp). But if your package contains any debconf templates for setting up, you should use [po-debconf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/po-debconf.7.html) to allow translations for those templates.